webcam video stream for capturing photo not working
[enter image description here][1]I am trying to get access to webcam and display video stream for capturing photo. I am  getting consent for camera access i.e. popup message and when i allow the access the front camera indicator light is coming but there is nothing visible on webpage and capture photo button is also not working  .I searched a lot but couldn't find anything.
Below is the code for it:
app.js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    const video = document.getElementById('video');
    const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    const captureButton = document.getElementById('capture');
    const photoData = document.getElementById('photo_data');

    // Get access to the camera
    if (navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true }).then(function(stream) {
            console.log("Camera stream obtained");
            video.srcObject = stream;
            video.play();
        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.log("Error accessing camera: " + error);
            alert("Could not access the camera. Please check permissions.");
        });
    } else {
        alert("getUserMedia is not supported by your browser.");
    }

    // Capture photo
    captureButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
        const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 320, 240);
        const dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
        photoData.value = dataURL;
        canvas.style.display = 'block';
    });
});

function submitForm() {
    const photoData = document.getElementById('photo_data').value;
    if (!photoData) {
        alert("Please capture a photo before submitting the form.");
        return false;
    }
    return true; // Ensures the form is submitted
}


this is my .php file from which i am accessing the webcam feature
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Visitor Form</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container mt-5 print-area">
        <h2>Visitor Form</h2>
        <form method="post" action="visitor_form.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return submitForm()">
            <div class="form-group">
    <label for="photo">Photo</label>
    <div style="display: flex; align-items: center;">
        <video id="video" width="320" height="240" autoplay></video>
        <button type="button" id="capture" class="btn btn-secondary" style="margin-left: 10px;">Capture Photo</button>
        <canvas id="canvas" width="320" height="240" style="display: none;"></canvas>
        <input type="hidden" name="photo_data" id="photo_data">
    </div>
</div>
    <script src="../js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>



i tried a lot and searched different articles but couldn't find anything.Kindly guide me.


  [1]: https://i.sstatic.net/3KnB14Bl.png


The navigator.permissions.query method doesn't prompt for permission; it only checks if permission has already been granted or denied. This means that the browser won’t show a camera access prompt based on this query alone. The getUserMedia API should handle this prompt when it's called.
Check the below code.
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    console.log("DOM fully loaded and parsed");

    const video = document.getElementById('video');
    const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    const captureButton = document.getElementById('capture');
    const photoData = document.getElementById('photo_data');

    if (!video || !canvas || !captureButton || !photoData) {
        console.error("Required elements are missing.");
        return;
    }

    if (navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true })
            .then(function(stream) {
                console.log("Camera stream obtained");
                video.srcObject = stream;
                video.play();
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                console.error("Error accessing camera:", error);
                alert("Could not access the camera. Please check permissions and ensure you're using HTTPS.");
            });
    } else {
        alert("getUserMedia is not supported by your browser.");
    }

    
    captureButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
        const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 320, 240); // Adjust dimensions as needed
        const dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
        photoData.value = dataURL;
        canvas.style.display = 'block';
    });
});

function submitForm() {
    const photoData = document.getElementById('photo_data').value;
    if (!photoData) {
        alert("Please capture a photo before submitting the form.");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

Also, some browsers only allow access to the camera via secure origins (HTTPS). If you’re testing locally, try running it on a localhost server or deploying the code to an HTTPS server.
And their could be previous saved browser settings to deny the access to the camera. Please check on it.

The navigator.permissions.query({ name: 'camera' }) is not universally supported in all browsers. Relying on this might not be effective. Instead, use a more straightforward check with navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia() directly.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Webcam Capture</title>
</head>
<body>
    <video id="video" autoplay playsinline width="320" height="240"></video>
    <button id="capture">Capture Photo</button>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="320" height="240" style="display: none;"></canvas>
    <input type="hidden" id="photo_data">
    <button onclick="submitForm()">Submit</button>

    <script>
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", async function () {
            const video = document.getElementById('video');
            const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
            const captureButton = document.getElementById('capture');
            const photoData = document.getElementById('photo_data');

            // Request access to the camera
            try {
                const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true });
                video.srcObject = stream;
                console.log("Camera stream obtained");
            } catch (error) {
                console.error("Error accessing camera: ", error);
                alert("Could not access the camera. Please check permissions or use HTTPS.");
                return;
            }

            // Capture photo
            captureButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
                const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
                context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                const dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
                photoData.value = dataURL;
                canvas.style.display = 'block';
                alert("Photo captured!");
            });
        });

        function submitForm() {
            const photoData = document.getElementById('photo_data').value;
            if (!photoData) {
                alert("Please capture a photo before submitting the form.");
                return false;
            }
            alert("Form submitted successfully with captured photo.");
            return true;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>



page pops up--  Could not access the camera. Please check permissions or use HTTPS.
